# Android Event Bus Alternative

Tags: android, android-asynctask, otto

Context: In a previous Android application I have developed, I used an **event bus** (**otto** by Square) to handle async task results (for example: the result of a server request is posted on the bus and somewhere in the application I intercept that response). Although it did the job, in some article I've read it was mentioned that using such a bus is rather a bad idea as it's considered an **antipattern**.

Why is that so? What are some alternatives to using an event bus when dealing with results of async operations? I know that, most of the time, there is no standard way to handle things, but is there "a more canonical" method?

Comment: RxJava - https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `RxJava` and `Retrofit` for asynchronous network calls. `RxJava` provide out of the box support for `Retrofit`.

Return `Observable` from retrofit interface.

```
@GET("/posts/{id}")
public Observable<Post> getData(@Path("id") int postId);
```

Use it in your activity class  -

```
retrofitBuilderClass.getApi()
 .getData()
 .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
 .subscribe(new Observer < List < Data >> () {
  @Override
  public void onCompleted() {

  }

  @Override
  public void onError(Throwable e) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onNext(List < Data > data) {
  // Display data
  }
 });
```

Comment: This is so cool! It perfectly suits my needs since I'm already using Retrofit! Thank you!